# Use custom Admin URL redirects to login screen

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, backend, base-url

I have the following problem:
My webshop is available from 2 different URL. One that works only in the company network and an external URL. The base URL is set to the internal URL. Now to get the webshop accessible from the internal and the external URL I turned off the auto-redirect to base url option. This works wonderful for the frontend. But if I try to access the backend from the external URL, I get redirected to the base URL (which is the internal URL) after pressing the login button. Because of that I can't access the backend if I am not in my companies network.

Is there a possibility to turn of the base url redirection for the backend?

**Update:**
Well I've found the "Use Custom Admin URL" option. After turning it on and set the URL to my external URL I can access the backend from outside of the companies network. But it didn't solve my problem. Now if I login to the backend and click on a link I get to the login screen. Although the URL changes to the clicked link. eg. I wan't to access the System -> Configuration the URL changes to: http://externalURL/admin/system_config/index/key/ANAUTOGENERATEDKEY/
And I get displayed the login screen but not the System -> Configuration interface. If I reload the page the login screen disappears and the system -> configuration interface gets displayed.
To sum up: after changing "Use Custom Admin URL" I need to reload the page after every link I try to open to get rid of the login screen and get to the clicked link.

Is this a common magento error?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to set other page instead of dashboard after login in admin

You can set it in admin configuration

```
Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Advance (Left) -> Admin -> Startup Page
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. No thats not what I am looking for. I've updated my question.